# Get combinations of custom class in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, combinations

I'm trying to get combinations of a list of objects of a custom class, I'm not sure it's possible though.

I want a combination of 2 Points. For example [Point(1,2) Point (2,3)]
Here is a sample:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random
import numpy as np
import itertools


class Point():
    """Describes a point"""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point(%s,%s)' % (self.x, self.y)


def get_combinations(c):
    dt = np.dtype([('', Point)]*2)
    combinations = np.fromiter((itertools.combinations(c, 2)), dtype=dt)
    print(combinations)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = np.array([Point(random.randint(0, 150), random.randint(0, 150))
         for x in range(2) for y in range(2)])
    print(c)
    get_combinations(c)
```

`dt = [('f0', 'O'), ('f1', 'O')]`

Am I missing something? I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    get_combinations(c)
  File "test.py", line 21, in get_combinations
    combinations = np.fromiter((itertools.combinations(c, 2)), dtype=dt)
ValueError: cannot create object arrays from iterator
```

Comment: What should the combinations be like?

Comment: It should be a combination of 2 points. For example [Point(1,2) Point (2,3)]

Comment: Your `dtype` contains object dtype - print `dt` or make a test array: `np.zeros(3, dt)`.  Like is says, you can't use `fromiter` with that kind of `dtype`.  `np.array(list(itertools...))` might work

Comment: @hpaulj i edited the question to include dt. Otherwise, np.array(list(itertools...)) works, but don't lose in performance?

Comment: Some performance is better than none!  But performance of object dtype arrays sucks, period.  Iterating over a list of the objects is often faster.

Comment: `np.array(list(itertools...), dtype=dt)` works better than I thought.  The data for `np.array(..., dt)` is supposed to be a list of tuples, matching the `dt` grouping.  And fortunately `list(itertools...)` produces just the list that we need.

Comment: You really should just use a list.